# What's the difference between QProcess::kill() and QProcess::terminate()?

Tags: c++, qt, difference, qprocess

I read some documentation but it isn't clear enough to me. I know that both "end" a process and that kill() is meant to force it to end, but what is terminate() supposed to do then?

Comment: If it's not in the documentation then it can't really be relied on.

Comment: I think that they are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dunno what's not clear if you have written:

> *void QProcess::kill()*
>
> **Kills the current process, causing it to exit immediately.**
>
> On Windows, kill() uses TerminateProcess, and on Unix and OS X, the SIGKILL signal is sent to the process.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill

---

> *void QProcess::​terminate()*
>
> Attempts to terminate the process.
>
> **The process may not exit as a result of calling this function (it is given the chance to prompt the user for any unsaved files, etc).**
>
> On Windows, terminate() posts a WM_CLOSE message to all toplevel windows of the process and then to the main thread of the process itself. On Unix and OS X the SIGTERM signal is sent.
>
> **Console applications on Windows that do not run an event loop, or whose event loop does not handle the WM_CLOSE message, can only be terminated by calling kill().**

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate

So, basically `​terminate()` is less brutal, but does not guarantee that process will be terminated.

On Unix `terminate()` uses SIGTERM signal, while `kill()` sends SIGKILL to the process. The difference between them is that SIGTERM can be caught by a process, which allows it to perform cleanup etc. SIGTERM can be ignored. SIGKILL will literally kill process, process can not ignore it.

On Windows [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is posted, when you call `terminate()`, so application can also gracefully handle it. `kill()` calls  [TerminateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is more or less Windows equvalent of SIGKILL.

I think `terminate()` SIGTERM and WM_CLOSE could be handled by Qt and translated into normal Qt events, but you have to try it yourself. You can of course handle them by system specific functions.

---

***"what causes terminate() to not exit the process."***

It is you, because you can catch `terminate()` signals/messages and do whatever you want, or it can be user of your application if he is prompted if he really wants to quit app. [Yet another resource on WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I read that. But considering I'm not working on a process with savable files, **what causes terminate() to not exit the process.** That's not clear for me.